# Markov chain - expected times to absorption

Tags: probability, probability-theory, markov-chains, markov-process

The expected times to absorption for Markov chain is calculated from the following equations:
[image: abs]

I would like to ask why `1` is there in the second equation.  Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because you take $1$ step and then you take whatever steps you expect to take in the state you transition to.

Comment: Thank you for clarifying it!